# Testing Server for JSON-RPC

Tags: api, postman, json-rpc

Is there a simple online testing server (similar to Postman-echo.com) that I can use for JSON-RPC commands from Postman or for any other simple scripts that I might be writing?

On GitHub, I see lots of [public APIs on GitHub](https://github.com/public-apis/public-apis) (many that don't even need keys), but I unfortunately don't see any for JSON-RCP that I could use.

I also stumbled across this [Guru JSON app](https://gurujsonrpc.appspot.com/), but it seems to only let me send JSON from the website, not from other apps like Postman.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found Random.org and just tested it in Postman.

https://api.random.org/json-rpc/1/invoke

Works great for learning purposes!